# How does wedding photographer post-process to achieve this rich detailed + high contrast portrait look?

Tags: post-processing, portrait, technique, reverse-engineering, wedding

Extremely rich in detail and contrast, which make the photo look very stand out (3D) and feels like looking at a masterpiece painting. I assumed this is not a 3 shot combined HDR photo (since involve some human interactive motion and shoot without tripod)

I not sure if this is a combination effort through techniques like tonal contrasts + tone mapping + sharpening + single photo pseudo-HDR

Anyone have any idea how to archive this effect in photoshop?

Both pictures taken by Edwin T@n
[image]
[image]

Comment: the first photo seems to be tone-mapped and then dodge&burned for the dark background.

Comment: *"tone mapping + sharpening + single photo pseudo-HDR"* that's pretty much it.

Comment: It also looks to me like there may be some selective color boosts too.  That purple looks over saturated compared to the faces in the first.

Comment: You mention Edwin Tan as photographer, and "fair use" may allow you to post the photos on this site, as the usual Imgur rules which would make this impermissible, have been modified for stacl exchange use, but it would be at a minimum polite to link back to a source image such as [**For the wedding, here on Edwin's site**](http://edwintcg.com/blog/2013/10/cafe-paris/) and [**For the shop - here on Edwin's site**](http://edwintcg.com/blog/2010/12/italy-street-shoot/). Note that many people post images like this without proper attribution and/or permission and you should find an 'official' site.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon will do next time, noted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photomatix 5 Enhanced preset comes very close to this look.  Adding a bit of high pass filtering in "soft light" mode seems to finish off the effect nicely.  But for me it was all about the lighting here.  Notice he has captured the viewers attention very well with the compositional light.  So if you're looking to catch a judge's eye in competition, look more at the compositional tricks used than the photo effects.  Those will produce a winner every time.